# Error filtering an array with my search bar vuejs2

Tags: vue.js, filter, searchbar, computed-properties

I'm trying to filter an array, which is cycled in a v-for, by using a search bar and i don't know why everything just disappear.I am currently cycling the function searchedRestaurant().
This is the error I got: this.all_restaurants.filter is not a function.
This is my code:

```
<div class="col" v-for="(restaurant, index) in searchedRestaurant()" :key="index">

data() {
    return{
        all_categories: {},
        all_restaurants: {},
        search: "" 
    }
}, 
computed: {
   searchedRestaurant: function(){
       return this.all_restaurants.filter((element) => {
          return element.business_name.match(this.search)
       })
   }
```

}

Comment: Try `v-for="(restaurant, index) in searchedRestaurant"` without the brackets.

Comment: You should avoid refering to computed properties as functions in template section, they are not functions they become variables furthermore.

Answer (score 0):

`all_categories` and `all_restaurants` should be arrays

```js
...
  all_categories: [],
  all_restaurants: []
...
```